# Which magento table contains product url slug

Tags: magento, magmi

The problem I'm having is that I import products with Magmi (magento product import open source solution), but I want to change the url slug. I need to know which table in magento database contains slug so that I could maybe feed it somehow directly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most excellent Magmi will do that for you. I suggest you read every single page of the [Magmi instructions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page) slowly and carefully to comprehend the enormous capabilities of this software tool. But the one you want to concentrate on is [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_new_products).

So if you use a CSV like:

```
"sku","url_key"
"00085722994075","my-awesome-product-you-will-fail-without-it"
```

Then Magmi will update all the product 'slugs' for you.

To answer your question: The core_url_rewrite is the main table but it is built from, among other things, the product attribute 'url_key' and the product attributes are in the EAV so it isn't a single table update. That is why we bow to the genius of Dweeves and his magical Magmi code.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is old and answer was accepted but for users do not using Magmi is there this answer:

URL Key is stored by EAV model.
You can find value by following query:

```
SELECT `attribute_id` INTO @urlKeyId 
FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `entity_type_id` = 4 AND `attribute_code` LIKE 'url_key';

SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id` = @urlKeyId;
```

(if you are using table prefix add it to table's names)

Answer (score 0):

i think better idea to load product then update product URL otherwise if you try to do in direct database table. some problems can come out like indexing , magento can stop working.

i means how you do load MAGE class then load product then do this manually